# There is an error msg when I use nicEditor in IE browser

Tags: nicedit

When I click backcolor button/change background color, there is an error msg "Invalid argument", does anyone know how to figure out this issue? thanks~
Btw: All IE versions

Comment: And IE browser is exactly what? IE8, IE9, IE10... IE5.5 perhaps?

Comment: All versions:(, you may test this official url: www.nicEdit.com in IE(6, 7, 8, 9). click the backcolor button, then choose any color, it shows that error msg.

Answer (score 1):

i find ..ie 9 browser
NicEdit background this.ne.nicCommand('hiliteColor',c) ==>this.ne.nicCommand('backColor',c)

The execCommand method is a method of the document, not the Range. Also, hilitecolor only works in Firefox, so you should fall back to using backcolor in WebKit and Opera.